# Path to the Folder where Widgets are stored!

Tags: mac, macos, notifications, widgets

There are lots of useless widgets in the notification center of macOS, so does anyone knows where these widgets are stored in the system, I want the path to that folder in-order to remove the useless ones to the trash.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Part of CoreServices

The widgets are stored within `/System/Library/CoreServices`. They are plug-ins of small applications of the same name.

### Finding Widgets

Widgets contain an `Info.plist` file containing the text `com.apple.widget-extension`. You can use this text to search for other widgets.

A full disk search from the command line would be:

```
grep -r 'com.apple.widget-extension' /
```

### System Integrity Protection

Note that these widgets are protected by macOS's [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (SIP). This means you can not remove these widgets without first disabling SIP.

Apple recommends you do not modify the contents of the `/System` folder on your Mac. Changing the contents of this folder can result in unexpected behaviour from macOS.

Comment: Okay I found calendar and stocks widget under this folder but didn't found the file for social(widget)

Comment: I forgot to add sudo before grep now the shell is in running condition so should I terminate the terminal window without the finishing of the process? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk8vp.png)

Comment: The permission errors can be safely ignored. They occur for files you can not read as a user. Many are temporary caches or log files, such as `.fseventsd` for the drive's file system event log.